# Описать не только методы, но и свойства объектов в gitbook

Tags: объекты, документация

Пишу документацию по [lua](/questions/tagged/lua) модулю. В нём фигурирует объект, у которого кроме методов есть ещё и свойства. В свою очередь, плагин *theme-api* для *gitbook* позволяет описать только методы. Как, в таком случае, описать свойства объекта в *gitbook*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У него нет такого так как он сделан для описания веб-сервисов. Посмотрите исходники, они небольшие - там нигде нет упоминания о переменных класса.

Comment: И что теперь? Учить js и писать свой модуль?

Comment: Попробуйте плагин наподобие https://www.npmjs.com/package/gitbook-plugin-phpclassdisplayer правда он для PHP а не Lua, так что вам скорее всего придётся писать что-то подобное для него т.к в Сети я ничего не нашёл.

Comment: Вы сможете использовать этот плагин, заменив при необходимости его тэги с PHP на LUA - ведь все остальное это просто стили для отображения переменных класса.